# All tables in the bracketed expression must have the same variable names

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I have two editable numeric fields and a table in app designer; the user can enter the values in these editable fields and then push a button. Then, the values are added to a table. Also, I provide an option to attach an excel folder that should have two columns to reflect on the table.
Both of these work perfectly fine individually, but, if I added the values manually then attached an excel folder or vice versa, I get the following error: All tables in the bracketed expression must have the same variable names.
The function that handles the editable fields:

```
  app.t = app.UITable.Data;
            x = app.xvalueEditField.Value;
            y = app.yvalueEditField.Value;
            nr = table(x, y);
            app.UITable.Data = [app.t; nr];  %% error happens here if I attach excel then add manually
            app.t = app.UITable.Data;
```

The Function of the excel folder:

```
text = readtable([pathname filename], "Sheet",1, 'ReadVariableNames',false);
       fl = cellfun(@isnumeric,table2cell(text(1,:))); 
if (numel(fl(fl == false)) > 0) 
    flag = false;
else
    flag = true;
end
if (flag)
            A = [app.t; text];  %% error happens here if I add manually then attach
            app.UITable.Data = A;
            app.t = text; 
end
```

Note: these are only the parts of the function, where I attempt to combine values

Can someone please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `table` only allows you to vertically concatenate tables when the `'VariableNames'` properties match. This is documented here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html#btxzag0-1 .

In your first code example, the table `nr` will have variable names `x` and `y` (derived from the names of the underlying variables you used to construct the table). You could fix that case by doing:

```
% force nr to have the same VariableNames as app.t:
nr = table(x, y, 'VariableNames', app.t.Properties.VariableNames);
```

and in the second case, you can force `text` to have the correct variable names like this:

```
text.Properties.VariableNames = app.t.Properties.VariableNames
```